# How to add one more path in SSIS data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

[image]

Hi,

I try to use same data twice in SSIS data flow panel, however, it only allow me to build one path, is there anyway I can build another path of it or I can duplicate the data I want to use?

Thanks,

Comment: All three answers below are correct, please select one as the answer to stop people from coming here to answer your question. thanks

Comment: @all, Thanks you guys, that's great helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add a path, it depends on your requirements:

1. [Multicast transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/multicast-transformation)

> The Multicast transformation distributes its input to one or more outputs. This transformation is similar to the Conditional Split transformation. Both transformations direct an input to multiple outputs. The difference between the two is that the Multicast transformation directs every row to every output, and the Conditional Split directs a row to a single output

2. [Script Component multiple outputs](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2017/08/22/using-the-ssis-script-component-with-multiple-outputs/)

If you are looking to create many distinct path based on the script component code, then script component allow creating many outputs. *(check the link above for more details)*

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for multi cast transformation.
Connect the above 'CONVERT DATA TYPE2' TO 'MULICAST TRANSFORMATION'.
From multicast you can take anynumber of outtflows.

[image: Below is a sample]

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

The best and most SSIS way of doing this is by using the Multicast component. Connect it to the output path of your Script Transformation "Convert data type 2" and from there, you can connect it to both "Sort 1" and "Sort 3"

### Option 2

If your Script Transformation is asynchronous (1 row in to many rows out, many rows in to 1 out, etc) then you could add a second output and also send the data along.  That answer is only provided for completeness. Doing this would cause the amount of data required for a row in your pipeline to double (the Multicast component does some pointer reference voodoo to not physically duplicate the data)

Finally, I'm not sure what business problem you're solving but if performance is an issue, it'll be the package design and not SSIS itself. Without knowing more (aka a difference quest